# Is the sign of principal components meaningless?

Tags: pca, svd

Does the sign of the vectors returned by PCA have any significance after I center my variables?

Comment: Short answer: no. Both the negative and the positive vectors are valid Principal Components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not important.
From Wikipedia on SVD:

> Non-degenerate singular values always have unique left and right singular vectors, up to multiplication by a unit phase factor (for the real case **up to sign**).

So the signs of the principal components (which correspond to singular vectors) are undetermined.